# Method Not Allowed (POST) - code 405 and blank page

Tags: python, django, authentication

I create login page with html form:

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name="loginInput" id="loginField" placeholder="Login" required="required" class="form-control"/><br/>
   <input type="password" name="passwordInput" id="passwordField"maxlength="30" placeholder="Hasło" required="required" class="form-control"/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj się" class="loginbtn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"/><br/><br/>
</form>
```

and with `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class AuthForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

and of course `views.py`:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = AuthForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('users:index')
```

But when click  submit button app return blank page with this:

> Method Not Allowed (POST): / [05/Mar/2017 00:15:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1"
>   405 0

Anybody can help me find where I do make mistake?

Thanks

Comment: I think your CRSF token could not be verified.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the CSRF token, but to do with the url you are sending your POST request to. You are sending the request to your root file ("/") but should instead be sending the request to the same page ("").  In other notes, it is good practice to have else statements with your ifs. What if the form is not valid? what if the user typed in incorrect information?

Comment: @Raj it is much better to ask a new question rather than editing this one. I'm going to roll back your changes.